# Pick up weapons and equipping them, if weapon limit reached, replace our weapon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a weapon switching system that is very simple, I have a list of weapons and I can cycle through them using my scroll wheel

```
    int previousSelectedWeapon = selectedWeapon;

    if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f)
    {
        if(selectedWeapon - 1 >= 0)
        {
            selectedWeapon--;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedWeapon = maxWeapons;
        }
    }

    if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f)
    {
        if(selectedWeapon + 1 <= maxWeapons)
        {
            selectedWeapon++;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedWeapon = 0;
        }
    }

    if(previousSelectedWeapon != selectedWeapon)
    {
        SelectWeapon();
    }
}

public void SelectWeapon()
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
    {
        if (i ==  selectedWeapon)
        {
            weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

However this is not exactly what I'm looking for, I want to be able to have a maximum of x weapons currently equipped and I can only cycle through them.

Let's say I have 1 weapon I can pick up another weapon, but if I have the max amount of weapons equipped, I want my currently selected weapon to be replaced by the weapon I'm picking up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I fixed this code completely. Put only the content inside the code in the class. The bottom system works like switching weapons in `GTA`. If you want the list rotation to be locked, leave a comment again.

```cs
public class WeaponSelect : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int selectedWeapon = 0;
    private void Update()
    {
        var deltaY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        if (deltaY == 0) return;

        if (deltaY > 0) selectedWeapon = ++selectedWeapon % transform.childCount;

        if (deltaY < 0) selectedWeapon = selectedWeapon == 0 ? transform.childCount-1 : --selectedWeapon;

        SelectWeapon(selectedWeapon);
    }

    public void SelectWeapon(int index)
    {
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform) weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        transform.GetChild(index).gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change just maxWeapon to `weapon.Count` if it's a List or `weapon.Length` if it's a array;
Add new weapon to list, and set selected as a last element of list?